# After activity-alias name change for MainActivity, app icon is removed after app update

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I was using activity-alias to support different app icon for a particular device as below code :

```
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-Vendor"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo_vendor"
        android:label="@string/app_name_vendor"
        android:exported="true"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

----- Defining MainActivity app icon and text :

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

and It was working fine till Android 7.0 but when I targeted my app to Android 8.0 where activity-alias name is not supported with hyphen (-), So I changed the activity-alias name as below,

MainActivity-Vendor   --->    MainActivityVendor

and I also changed activity-alias enabled/disabled code based on device vendor as below :

Old code :

```
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    // Enable/disable activity-aliases
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivity-Vendor"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
    );

    int enabled = pm.getComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivity"));


    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivity"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
    );
```

New Code :

```
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    // Enable/disable activity-aliases
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivityVendor"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
    );

    int enabled = pm.getComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivity"));


    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivity"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
    );
```

Please note that, In above also I changed the code from,

MainActivity-Vendor  ---> MainActivityVendor

But after the app upgrade the app icon disappeared for the users. and also after the app upgrade user do not get the "open" option for the app. Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: Although I did not find exact solution but I managed to achieve this by doing following : 

         <receiver android:name=".AppUpdateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Then Handling alias enabled/disabled in the AppUpdateReceiver class. It solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not find exact solution but I managed to achieve this by doing following :

```
     <receiver android:name=".AppUpdateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then Handling activity-alias enabled/disabled in the AppUpdateReceiver class.

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Gaana App updated : " + intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Log.v(TAG, "app is updated - " + intent.getAction());
    mContext = context;
    if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED")) {
        MmxUtils.init();
        if (MmxUtils.isMmxBuild()) {
            setIcon();
        }
    }
}

private void setIcon() {
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

// Enable/disable activity-aliases
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivityVendor"),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
);

int enabled = pm.getComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivity"));


pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        new ComponentName(this, "com.app.MainActivity"),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
);
}
```

It solves my issue.